# read variables from a blank file in python

Tags: python, variables, overwrite

[image]

If I have a folder structure like the attached picture. The test.config.py is an empty file.
The default.py contains name variables indicate default folder root and addin information

```
local_root = r'c:\temp\project\cache'
local_input = local_root + r'inputs'
local_output = local_root + r'outputs'
addin_location = r'c:\user\...
addin_name = r'project_addin'
addin_version = r'1.1'
```

The setting.py contains name variables to overwrite addin information for testing.

```
addin_location = r'd:\user\...
addin_name = r'project_addin'
addin_version = r'2.1'
```

I want to import all variables from default.py and all variables from setting.py to init.py. Then overwrite variables with the same names imported from default.py use setattr(). i.e the addin_location, addin_name, and addin_version in default.py share the same name as variables in setting.py, thus overwrite those with setting.py.

Lastly, for any test.py files in test folder, it cannot refers to any of the variables using default.names or setting.names, but instead use config.names (basically the config.py should contain all variable names from default.py with overwritten information from setting.py, so that the codes in test.py only refer to the variable names in config.py). I have manually updated all reference to config.py but don't know how to put all variable names to config.py as it is an empty file. I think need to write some functions in init.py to dump those variable names to config.py

Thanks for the help.

Comment: apologize, I am too green for using stackoverflow. click "enter image description here" for picture. :)

Comment: Welcome (back?) to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure to **ask a question** - "thanks for the help" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Your question should be *specific* - right now, it seems like you have some thoughts about what the program needs to do, but you haven't actually identified a *problem you've encountered* and need help with. Please *try to write the code first*, so that you can identify such a problem (or who knows, maybe it will turn out to be easy if you just stick with it, a bit at a time).

Comment: "click "enter image description here" for picture. :)" [Please do not use images for things that can be plain text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). To show directory structures, try using the `tree` program at the command line, which will give you an ascii-art version that experiences programmers are familiar with. (This should be built in on Windows, and easy to install on Mac or Linux if your distribution doesn't have it). Copy and paste the text, [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) like code.

Comment: "but don't know how to put all variable names to config.py as it is an empty file." It's hard to make sense of this, because we can't see your data structures, or what you tried so far, or any example input or output. Please read [mre].

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to dynamically create variable *names* and enter them into a file. While this is common practice in some languages (STATA is the only one I know of), this is very bad practice in python. Instead, you can store data with dynamic key names using data structures like dictionaries.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I think I found a way to complete this. I created a class in default.py and a dictionary in setting.py and then uses set to find the common variable names. After that use setattr to update. In the end, write the final class in default.py to config.py. Then initialize this function in init.py.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to keep a track of those config in a file or do you just want to access all information from the combine default.py + any setting.py overwrite ?

For the latter, I think you can use dataclasses:

```py
# default.py
from dataclasses import dataclass

# Here I am defining the default parameters for the class instance
@dataclass
class Config:
    local_root: str = r'c:\temp\project\cache'
    local_input: str = local_root + r'inputs'
    local_output: str = local_root + r'outputs'
    addin_location: str = r'c:\user\...'
    addin_name: str = r'project_addin'
    addin_version: str = r'1.1'
```

Then in setting you can instantiate the class by replacing by placing all overwriting values in a dict.

```py
# setting.py
from .default import Config
overwrite_settings = {
    "addin_location": r'd:\user\...',
    "addin_name": r'project_addin',
    "addin_version": r'2.1'
}

config = Config(**overwrite_settings)
```

Then in your test file you can import the config object and access the variable as follow:

```py
# test.py
from .setting import config

my_path_root = config.local_root
```

And if you want to use init just instantiate the class in the init.py file and import the config with it:

```py
#init.py
from .setting import overwrite_settings
from .default import Config

config = Config(**overwrite_settings)
```

For the former I am not sure how to save directly into a ready to use python file. Especially at run time, it might be tricky.
But if you want to keep a track of the config that you run you can add a
`__post_init__` method to your class in order to save it to a json for example:

```py
# default.py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Config:
    local_root: str = r'c:\temp\project\cache'
    local_input: str = local_root + r'inputs'
    local_output: str = local_root + r'outputs'
    addin_location: str = r'c:\user\...'
    addin_name: str = r'project_addin'
    addin_version: str = r'1.1'

    def __post_init__(self):
        with open('run_config.json', 'r') as file:
            json.dump(self.__dict__, file)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: well i did that just writing to a file and reading to a file just a dict, with separation on : or = in each line

Comment: @Vincet Richard Thank you for sharing your thoughts and codes. It seems you create a Config class in the default.py file, but the config.py file is not used. For all test.py files, if I want to refer to any variables use config.name (from Test import config, config.local_root......), waht shall I do? Additionally,  the dataclasses module seems not available in python 3.6. I am not allowed to use higher version of python.

Comment: Hello, there a solution for dataclasses with python 3.6. There is has been backport, so you can install it as an [external library](https://pypi.org/project/dataclasses/).